# Prevent Children from Triggering Hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a final project I'm working on for a class that requires the use of a form on one page. Long story short, I want to have the form display when hovering over a "contact" button. However, when hovering in the space the form occupies, it *also* appears. How can I remove the hover event from firing on a node's children *without* JavaScript? This is a basic web authoring class, so I don't want to use JavaScript unless necessary.

I also want to keep the transition on the `.droptainer`. Setting `display: none` to `display: block` on hover removes the transition since the display property can't be animated.

```css
/* styles for the navigation menu */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / repeat(5, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;    
}

nav>ul::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
    
    float: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 500ms;
}

nav ul li a {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: .7em 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: floralwhite;
}

/* styles for the dropdown form */

.droptainer {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 60%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 2em 10%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 12px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  transform: translatey(-5%);
  transition: 600ms 250ms;
  
}

.drop_btn:hover > .droptainer {
  transform: translatey(5%);
  opacity: 1;  
}

.droptainer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1.75em;
  }
```

```html
 <nav class="nav_menu" role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="nav/ingredients.html">Ingredients</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="nav/fish.html">Fish</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/condiments.html">Condiments</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/others.html">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="nav/history.html">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="nav/trivia.html">Trivia</a></li>
      <li class="drop_btn">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <div class="droptainer">
          <h3>Sign up for the latest sushi news</h3>
          <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label>I want to sign up for SushiNews.</label>
            <button>Submit</button>
            <button>Reset</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `pointer-events: none` as long as the droptainer is `hidden`:

```css
/* styles for the navigation menu */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / repeat(5, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav>ul::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 500ms;
}

nav ul li a {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: .7em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: floralwhite;
}


/* styles for the dropdown form */

.droptainer {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 60%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 2em 10%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 12px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  transform: translatey(-5%);
  transition: 600ms 250ms;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.drop_btn:hover>.droptainer {
  transform: translatey(5%);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.droptainer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1.75em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_menu" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="nav/ingredients.html">Ingredients</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="nav/fish.html">Fish</a></li>
        <li><a href="nav/vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
        <li><a href="nav/condiments.html">Condiments</a></li>
        <li><a href="nav/others.html">Others</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="nav/history.html">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="nav/trivia.html">Trivia</a></li>
    <li class="drop_btn">
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <div class="droptainer">
        <h3>Sign up for the latest sushi news</h3>
        <form>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text">
          <input type="text">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <label>I want to sign up for SushiNews.</label>
          <button>Submit</button>
          <button>Reset</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So elegant and simple. Exactly what I was looking for, and I get to learn about a new property. Bravo, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set the `display` to `none` by default, and then simply set it to `block` on hover (toggling the `display` as opposed to the `opacity`).

Unfortunately, a caveat of this is that `transition` won't work on the `display` property, so your element will appear immediately -- though this may suffice.

```css
/* styles for the navigation menu */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / repeat(5, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;    
}

nav>ul::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
    
    float: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 500ms;
}

nav ul li a {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: .7em 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: floralwhite;
}

/* styles for the dropdown form */

.droptainer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 60%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 2em 10%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 12px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  transform: translatey(-5%);
  transition: 600ms 250ms;
  
}

.drop_btn:hover > .droptainer {
  transform: translatey(5%);
  display: block; 
}

.droptainer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1.75em;
  }
```

```html
<nav class="nav_menu" role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="nav/ingredients.html">Ingredients</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="nav/fish.html">Fish</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/condiments.html">Condiments</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/others.html">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="nav/history.html">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="nav/trivia.html">Trivia</a></li>
      <li class="drop_btn">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <div class="droptainer">
          <h3>Sign up for the latest sushi news</h3>
          <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label>I want to sign up for SushiNews.</label>
            <button>Submit</button>
            <button>Reset</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Another option would be to toggle `visibility` as opposed to `opacity`. This allows you to keep the `transition`... but the element will still initially appear at the top of the page, and *then* move (likely undesirably). You may be able to offset this by playing with positioning though.

```css
/* styles for the navigation menu */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / repeat(5, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;    
}

nav>ul::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
    
    float: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 500ms;
}

nav ul li a {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: .7em 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: floralwhite;
}

/* styles for the dropdown form */

.droptainer {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 60%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 2em 10%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 12px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  transform: translatey(-5%);
  transition: 600ms 250ms;
  
}

.drop_btn:hover > .droptainer {
  transform: translatey(5%);
  visibility: visible;  
}

.droptainer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1.75em;
  }
```

```html
<nav class="nav_menu" role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="nav/ingredients.html">Ingredients</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="nav/fish.html">Fish</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/condiments.html">Condiments</a></li>
          <li><a href="nav/others.html">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="nav/history.html">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="nav/trivia.html">Trivia</a></li>
      <li class="drop_btn">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <div class="droptainer">
          <h3>Sign up for the latest sushi news</h3>
          <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label>I want to sign up for SushiNews.</label>
            <button>Submit</button>
            <button>Reset</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution and to make it short and to make you understand easy:

change your code

```
.droptainer {
  opacity:0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 60%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 2em 10%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 12px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  transform: translatey(0);
  transition: 600ms 250ms;


}
```

and

```
.drop_btn:hover  .droptainer {
  transform: translatey(5%);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;

}
```

It will  give you perfect transition only at clicking on the button. 
White space issues has been handled.

NOTE: Remember using transition with visibility not display.